# how to save click event to local storage to hide popup from user. He need to click accept once. If he ll click cancel the popup should opens again

Tags: javascript

how to save click event to local storage to hide popup from user. He need to click accept once. If he ll click cancel the popup should opens again

https://jsfiddle.net/npdqq2dt/5/

```
<div id="overlay">
  <div class="popup">
    <div id="popup_terms">
      blablabla
    </div>
    <button id="accept" type="button">accept</button>
    <button id="cancel" type="button">cancel</button>
  </div>
</div>


#overlay {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.45);
    z-index: 999;
    -webkit-animation: fade .6s;
    -moz-animation: fade .6s;
    animation: fade .6s;
    overflow: auto;
}
.popup {
    color: #525252;
    background: #0c2333;
    top: 20%;
    left: 0px;
    right: 0;
    font-size: 14px;
    margin: auto;
    width: 65%;
    height: 600px;
    min-width: 350px;
    max-width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    padding: 40px 65px;
    z-index: 1000;
}
```

Can u provide the solution using JQuery ? thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need jQuery to manipulate the local storage. Here a simple example:

```
$(function() {
  if (localStorage.getItem('popup_accepted')) {
    $('#overlay').remove();
  } else {
    $('#accept').click(function() {
      localStorage.setItem('popup_accepted');
      $('#overlay').remove();
    });

    $('#cancel').click(function() {
      $('#overlay').remove();
    });
  }
});
```

I can't create a working snippet because we don't have access to `localStorage` in a snippet.

Answer (score 0):

Using Javascript function to get and set cookie

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
    <style>
        #overlay {
            position: fixed;
            top: 0;
            left: 0;
            display: none;
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.45);
            z-index: 999;
            -webkit-animation: fade .6s;
            -moz-animation: fade .6s;
            animation: fade .6s;
            overflow: auto;
        }

        .popup {
            color: #525252;
            background: #0c2333;
            top: 20%;
            left: 0px;
            right: 0;
            font-size: 14px;
            margin: auto;
            width: 65%;
            height: 600px;
            min-width: 350px;
            max-width: 100%;
            position: absolute;
            padding: 40px 65px;
            z-index: 1000;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <button id="btn">Open Overlay</button>
    <div id="overlay">
        <div class="popup">
            <div id="popup_terms">
                blablabla
            </div>
            <button id="accept" type="button">accept</button>
            <button id="cancel" type="button">cancel</button>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8="
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script>
        $(function () {
            var storageName = 'rememberMe';
            $('#btn').on('click', function () {
                if (localStorage.getItem(storageName)) {
                    return false;
                } else {
                    $('#overlay').show();
                }
            });

            $('#accept').on('click', function () {
                localStorage.setItem(storageName, true);
                $('#overlay').hide();
            });

            $('#cancel').on('click', function () {
                $('#overlay').hide();
            });
        });
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: It won't work in any web based IDE because they do not allow to write any cookie. You can test it in your local machine.

Comment: Why a solution with cookies when the question is about local storage ?

Comment: Ohhh I missed that part.. let me change it.

Comment: As i said in my own answer, the code snippet won't work because of this error: `SecurityError: The operation is insecure.` (we don't have access to localStorage in a code snippet). But your code is now fine.